# getting null value after inserting numeric(6,6) datatype in postgres table

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion

I have a problen when I declare my type `rate` as `numeric(6,6)` and try to insert the record below I get no value in rate column.

```
insert into md.day_summations_usage (status_id,rate) values (200,0.000001)
```

Comment: Sorry - don't believe you. Can you post a complete SQL script reproducing your problem? Start with CREATE TABLE through to SELECTing the results. Oh - and PostgreSQL version too please.

Comment: sure, there was something wrong with one of my after insert triggers

Comment: that above problem is solved, but i have 1 more question. If i multiple 0.000001*3078343  i get 3.078343 and when i want to insert that result into a column with data type numeric(8,8) it says ERROR:  numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 8, scale 8 must round to an absolute value less than 1. what data type should the column be for it to hold 3.078343?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NUMERIC type definition ([manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)):

> NUMERIC(precision, scale)

If scale is equal precision then the value must be less than 1.
The correct type definition to insert 3.078343 value:

> NUMERIC(7,6)